# How can I filter through my array which contains a key with multiple string values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have a JSON file like this:

```
[{
    "movie": "The Dark Knight",
    "description": "The caped crusader protects Gotham from new evil.",
    "director": "Christopher Nolan",
    "genres": "superhero, thriller, action",
    "year": "2008"
}, {
    "movie": "IT Chapter Two",
    "description": "Pennywise returns once more 27 years later.",
    "director": "Andrés Muschietti",
    "genres": "horror, mystery",
    "year": "2019"
}, {
    "movie": "Avengers: Endgame",
    "description": "The Avengers have a last stand against Thanos.",
    "director": "Anthony Russo",
    "genres": "action, superhero",
    "year": "2019"
}]
```

I want to create a filter function that would allow me to filter through the entire array of objects and return a new array that contains the filtered objects. My function is like this:

```
function myfilter(genres) {
    let myJSON = parseJSON();
    var newArray = myJSON.filter(function (item) {
        return item.genres === genres
    });
    console.log(newArray);
}
```

The problem is, this function will work for any of the other keys but not for the "genres" key. I want to feed it an input like: `myfilter(['action', 'superhero']);`

And should return:

```
[{
    "movie": "The Dark Knight",
    "description": "The caped crusader protects Gotham from new evil.",
    "director": "Christopher Nolan",
    "genres": "superhero, thriller, action",
    "year": "2008"
},{
    "movie": "Avengers: Endgame",
    "description": "The Avengers have a last stand against Thanos",
    "director": "Anthony Russo",
    "genres": "action, superhero",
    "year": "2019"
}]
```

Comment: JSON is a text format, so there's [no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). You're just filtering an array of objects.

Comment: do you want to seach for both genres (handed over by parameter) or is one enough?

Comment: I want to be able to feed it any array of strings and have it filter through everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the genres string of the objects and check if some of the string is included in the genres array.

This solution feature two approaches,

1. get all items with only one matching genre `filterSome`,
2. get all items with all genres matching `filterEvery`.

The main difference is the use of [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) respectively [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
function filterSome(array, genres) {
    return array.filter(function (item) {
        var keys = item.genres.split(/,\s*/);
        return genres.some(g => keys.includes(g));
    });
}

function filterEvery(array, genres) {
    return array.filter(function (item) {
        var keys = item.genres.split(/,\s*/);
        return genres.every(g => keys.includes(g));
    });
}

var array = [{ movie: "The Dark Knight", description: "The caped crusader protects Gotham from new evil.", director: "Christopher Nolan", genres: "superhero, thriller, action", year: "2008" }, { movie: "IT Chapter Two", description: "Pennywise returns once more 27 years later.", director: "Andrés Muschietti", genres: "horror, mystery", year: "2014" }, { movie: "Avengers: Endgame", description: "The Avengers have a last stand against Thanos", director: "Anthony Russo", genres: "action", year: "2019" }];

console.log(filterSome(array, ['action', 'superhero']));
console.log(filterEvery(array, ['action', 'superhero']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.